# Angular 4 + material 2 : AOT compilation fails with server rendering

Tags: angular, webpack, compilation, aot, server-side-rendering

One year after, [this bug](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/308) is still unsolved. When I import material 2 inside my angular 4 project, my AOT compilation is throwing me this insult :

```
/dist/ngfactory/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.ngfactory.ts:9
import * as i0 from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

If you have even a fraction of idea, I'm taking it!
Thank you!

Comment: Which version are you using? I am using [material 2 with angular-cli](https://github.com/JayChase/ngx-express-universal) without getting the ES6 import issue.

Comment: I'm using :
@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/compiler-cli@4.4.1
@angular/cli@1.4.2
typescript@2.5.2
Pretty updated actually, I updated my whole package.json about an hour ago

Comment: Did you use the angular-cli [wiki guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) for the setup? The repo I linked to works ok. If you are getting import statements in your server build it would be worth check the tsconfig.json for the server has commonjs as the module format.

Comment: I'll check this out right now and tell you. Seems familiar to what I made but with a few differences.
During this time, did you check this out ? https://gist.github.com/gdi2290/6227a94d480b8c71123e1d7dd8dd2e58

Comment: Thank you very much for the link you gave me, it didn't solve my issue, however my setup seems more complete now.
Basically my dist-server compiles without any issue, but my dist still gives me the same error. Any idea ?

Comment: I modified my project to build my project the exact same way, now npm run server gives me the following error : 
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import 'reflect-metadata';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: Have you tried after this `npm install enhanced-resolve` ?

Comment: Doesn't work :/
I'm just going to use the repo that JayChase made, I'm going to earn some time! Merci beaucoup! You did a good job Jay! ;-)

Comment: @JayChase you should add service-worker to your seed, it would be awesome ;-)
https://medium.com/@cdeniz/transforming-an-existing-angular-application-into-a-progressive-web-app-d48869ba391f

Comment: I agree. Hopefully I will get a PWA branch finished in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: Awesome! You should also add compression and caching to server.ts, I just did it ;-)